# Как поменять расширение загруженного через ajax изображения?

Tags: python, ajax, django

Через ajax загружаю изображение, и сервере принимаю так:

```
@csrf_exempt
def ajax_img_loadDef(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':        

        # получит изображение
        img_load = request.FILES['img_load']

        # конвертировать gif в jpg
        # 

        return HttpResponse('success')
```

Вот, и мне, как и в комменте указано, нужно ЗАМЕНИТ ИЗОБРАЖЕНИЕ С РАСШИРЕНИЕМ GIF НА JPG.
Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: воспользуйтесь `PIL`, а именно `Image.open('prev.gif').convert('RGB').save('prev.jpg')`

Answer (score 0):

@5c0rp воспользуйтесь PIL, а именно:

```
Image.open('prev.gif').convert('RGB').save('prev.jpg')
```